# Prove row space of matrix is the same as row space of reduced row form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix, prove that Row($A$) = Row($R$) where $R$ is the rref of $A$.

The elementary matrix theorem could be useful, so

$A = E_k ... E_1 R$, where $E_k , ... , E_1$ are elementary matrices from a single ERO, how can I proceed with elementary linear algebra?

Comment: If $A=BR$, where $B$ is an *invertible* matrix, what can you say about the row spaces of $A$ and $R$ now? Try to construct a one-one onto map from one row space to the other (of course, you require $B$ for the definition).

Comment: How do the elementary row operations change the rows of $A$ to form the rows of $R$? Can these ever yield vectors that aren't in the row space of $A$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1998138/265466.