# How to prove two subspaces are equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vector spaces, $A$ and $B$, and one subspace from each, $U$ and $W$, respectively. How can I prove these subspaces are equal?

If it matters, in this case $A$ is a matrix with components in $\mathbb{R}$. Taking each row as a vector,  $U$ is a subspace from $\mathbb{R}^n$ generated by these vectors. Then I have $B$, which is RREF of $A$, and I take each of its rows as vectors and $W$ is the subspace generated by these vectors.

Also, how can I prove the vectors obtained from non-null rows of $B$ are linearly independent?

Comment: I think you are asking how to show that [row operations don't change the row space of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998138/elementary-row-operations-on-a-dont-change-the-row-space-of-a)?

Comment: @angryavian Wow, thanks. This helped a lot.